# Js+PHP: Reading values from text file

Tags: javascript, php, parsing

I'm trying to read values from a text file on **server** usin php and use them in js. I am using the code (found in stackoverflow) which seems to target what I need, but get an error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <) which seem related to the php line.

LM.txt hat one line: ID,LAT,LNG

```
 <script >   (function(){
     <?php echo "var fileContent = '" . file_get_contents("graphdata/LM.txt"). "'," ; ?>
     alerts = fileContent.split("\n").map(function(lineItem){
        // Assuming each line is csv: ID,LAT,LNG 
        // and that there are no commas in the values
        var field = lineItem.split(",");
        return {ID: field[0], LAT: field[1], LNG: fields[2]};
     });
     // now alerts looks like this: [{ID: ..., LAT: ..., LNG: ...}, {...}];   })(); </script>
```

Anything I can do?

Comment: This looks so wrong - you should definetly think about another way of solving this

Answer (score 0):

Does your script-file have a .PHP-extension? (Otherwise it won't be processed by the PHP-Interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

How about this, seem your code include some token in inline comment --> // now alert ...

```
<script >   
(function() {
    var fileContent = '<?php echo addslashes(file_get_contents("graphdata/LM.txt")) ?>',
    alerts = fileContent.split("\n").map( function(lineItem){
                  // Assuming each line is csv: ID,LAT,LNG    
                  // and that there are no commas in the values
                var field = lineItem.split(",");
                return { ID: field[0], LAT: field[1], LNG: fields[2] };
    });
   // now alerts looks like this: [{ID: ..., LAT: ..., LNG: ...}, {...}]; 
})();
</script>
```

Comment: That won't work. The value of fileContent will be the string '<?php echo addslashes(file_get_contents("graphdata/LM.txt")) ?>' and not the content of the file.

Comment: From your original code, it seem the code must parse by php. So <?php ... ?> is use for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
    $filecontent = str_replace("\n",'\n',file_get_contents("graphdata/LM.txt"));
    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var fileContent = "'.$filecontent.'";
            // now the JS variable fileContent has the content of your file
            var alerts = fileContent.split("\n").map(function(lineItem){
                 var field = lineItem.split(",");
                 return {ID: field[0], LAT: field[1], LNG: field[2]};
            });
        </script>
    ';
?>
```

Comment: It gives me some results but the parsed line has an error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL ):
 var fileContent = 'ID,LAT,LNG 
',

Comment: For some reason, fiddle is not loading. Could you post the code again?